# SQL count appearence that is 0

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose that I have 3 tables,

```
student(user_id, occupation)
thumbsup(user_id, post_id)
post(post_id, user_id)
```

I need to compute the number of good posts that one student has.
The conditions are like this

```
a post can receive multiple thumbs up
but once it receives at least one thumbup it is a goodpost
goodposts are how many posts that one user posted that received thumbsup
```

For example, if user_id 1 posts 3 posts with post_id, 3,4,5, 6 and post_id 3 receives 2 thumbs up, and post_id 4 receives 5 thumbs up and post_id 5 receives 10 thumbs up, 6 receives 0 thumbs up, that means user_id 1 has 3 good posts because 6 in this case has no thumbs up

I can sccuessfully project this by doing this. But there is one additional requirement:

```
 if a student does not have any good posts, their number of good posts should be zero.
```

This is my current solution that projects student if they have good posts

```
(SELECT temp2.user_id, S.occupation, goodpost
FROM 
(SELECT P.user_id, COUNT (P.user_id) as goodpost
FROM
(SELECT T.post_id, Count(*) AS likes
FROM swoosh.thumbsup T
group by T.post_id) As TEMP, swoosh.post P
WHERE P.post_id = temp.post_id
GROUP BY P.user_id) temp2, swoosh.Student S
WHERE temp2.user_id = S.user_id)
```

But I need to project those user_id who dont receive thumbs up too in this table. What is the approach

Comment: Do a left join so that you get all students and use `EXISTS` to identify good posts. Then group and count.

Comment: Can you show me the syntax, I tried to do it, but it doesnt work

Comment: I got it by using full join and coleasce but I hoenstly dont know how it works

Comment: Well, that's what your class is trying to teach you. Ask your teacher.